# RSA different values in Android and in Java Server

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I have an Android app that is sending data to a Java server. I'm encrypting the data with the following function:

```
public String encryptRSA(String text)
{
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        byte[] utf8 = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] enc = cipher.doFinal(utf8);

        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(enc), "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and decrypting with this one:

```
public String decryptRSA(String text)
{
    try {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        byte[] dec = Base64.decodeBase64(text);
        byte[] utf8 = cipher.doFinal(dec);

        return Base64.encodeBase64String(utf8);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

When I used them in the server, everything was working perfectly. The encryption/decryption was working, giving the right results. The problem happens when I try to decrypt in the server the information coming from the app.
(I've checked already and it's encrypting with the correct public key)

I wanted to encrypt this: iIXobbUgyc7Di3/CWBjRJw==. In my app, I get this: 
eq6c+uRLLsEq8k/Dbz9cbR/hqV7Nzy7miyUhXjPS4gGbq//wxy4P37a+tFW+C8RUyx+6QodkRbhjmPp0d3ZKYmuF0JKcPP/CEBGnvcHCWnkLPL++fuZ1ded9tBF1HU30kuD8ZH/WYuLBlq6izhQ1k3GdBx5m5lxdYFESoEuu2ToiH7PwaT3huwsZRed9YhbG/y+nMUEOXIUgMwJNBqXF1nb8+ws9l664CnwzsW9F6SwXCNQgfbt2ONpiLvOc6JgXk3SNHPRZDupmn2PquRChJvBGdESCklmnME0Kw7in7vuvbaRJtIvSfOm4r9Xb5Jf6DDFEspJjSmeznNwjsDdDAw==

In my server, I get this:
zxdx/OJW7lJh9GMdUIzmgPn57UTbVpPcEPFxOtKK2wVO0nw8u1RR2arT3XCxuh6EnmbzY345rBPt/jg1UcQVcqCRFQPrw/ldfT5xK1IK5yiLrtnKzRXxyQiEQypcAPuIL4CYrgr4Yk7WdTahugyPTiTxOin2J1D7LMJjHy0cRgTIqsN1uncHNNcjD912i5wGFwrFAiGzsm+kbQm3h5RMRrsFUiGj74YPkS3DcfKkvnwQ+B3FIu+BvTNvuahCSpCFUWPdheuZ0GJYVzluBJw+wUFqqgTF3vePiyrfhnX/y6J1JumOESSR1vWRDnTCtgkSRoo6Y9a2sOgysXq6guRlCA==

Obviously, when I decrypt I get a completely different value from the initial one.
Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
return Base64.encodeBase64String(utf8);
```

with

```
return new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
```

in your `decryptRSA`, if you wan't it to return what was passed to `encryptRSA` in the first place. This reverses what `byte[] utf8 = text.getBytes("UTF-8");` did in `encryptRSA`.